# enable BFD for checking link status

Tags: opendaylight, openvswitch

I am new to OpenVswitch. I am trying to enable BFD for checking link status,
can you please tell me how to enable it in open Vswitch.
and after making changes to enable BFD do we need to rebuild open Vswitch 
and how?

Thanks,
Pankaj

Answer (score 2):

There're many examples in https://github.com/openvswitch/ovs/blob/master/tests/bfd.at

```
OVS_VSWITCHD_START([add-br br1 -- set bridge br1 datapath-type=dummy -- \
                    add-port br1 p1 -- set Interface p1 type=patch \
                    options:peer=p0 ofport_request=2 -- \
                    add-port br0 p0 -- set Interface p0 type=patch \
                    options:peer=p1 ofport_request=1 -- \
                    set Interface p0 bfd:enable=true bfd:min_tx=300 bfd:min_rx=300 -- \
                    set Interface p1 bfd:enable=true bfd:min_tx=500 bfd:min_rx=500])
```

Other configurations: https://github.com/openvswitch/ovs/blob/a70f8b11087a780fe4a13ecd50c7aef05ef519cc/vswitchd/vswitch.xml#L2242